# Использование слова «полупрофессиональный»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Правильно ли говорить: «Полупрофессиональная бензопила»?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, есть же такое слово, его употребляют. К профессионализму это отношения не имеет, а означает примерно следующее: почти топ-продукт. Это и бензопила, и, к примеру, фотокамера, да все, что угодно. Градация такая: начальный уровень - "продвинутый" - полупроф - проф.

Comment: Градация, скорее: любительский - полупрофессиональный -  профессиональный